# Hebrew chars Encoding Issue in VBScript

Tags: xslt, utf-8, vbscript, asp-classic

I've recently changed the definition of all our xsl files to work with UTF-8:

```
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Also, I've changed some Infrastructure code that configures the encoding of the system to this:

```vb
Session.CodePage = 65001
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
Response.ContentType = "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
```

It used to be this under Hebrew language setting:

```vb
Session.CodePage = 1255
Response.CharSet = "windows-1255"
Response.ContentType = "text/html; charset=windows-1255"
```

Now, most of the output HTML would render fine, but there is one part of the system where it doesn't.
The Hebrew text sent in a form is seen OK in fiddler, then it is read in a binary fashion like this:

```vb
Request.BinaryRead(Request.Totalbytes)
```

and it looks like this:

```
%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%93%3A+%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A1+%D7%A0%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D+%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A8%
```

Then this line of code (Field's value comes from iterating through the request form:

```vb
URLDecode(Field(1))
```

makes the final output become something like this:

```
1D9D9DAD9D: 3D9D9D ADADAD9D 9D9D9DADAD: 3D9D9DAD/2D ADAD9D9DAD 9D9D9DAD9D 9D9D9D9D9D9DAD9D 9D9D9D9D9D ADADAD9D9D9D - AD9D9D9DAD
```

Instead of valid Hebrew and when I check Response.Charset it is `UTF-8`.

I would appreciate any hint on the issue.

Comment: I have added the `asp-classic` tag, hopefully that way the question is read by someone still familiar with those APIs and objects your code uses.

Comment: Looks like the form data is being encoded when it is sent, is the `<form>` set to send using `UTF-8` encoding?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is this octet stream being interpreted as Hebrew UTF-8 encoding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153883/how-is-this-octet-stream-being-interpreted-as-hebrew-utf-8-encoding). Should help you understand the issue.